# Data Migration from one DB to another

Tags: postgresql, data-migration, snowflake-schema

I have to create an app which transfer data from snowflake to postgres everyday. Some tables in postgres are truncated before migration and all data from corresponding snowflake table is copied. While for other tables, data after last timestamp in postgres is copied from snowflake.
This job has to run at night sometime and not when customers are using the service at daytime.
What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have constraints, limiting your choices in:

- ETL or bulk data tooling
- Development languages?

Comment: yes development language is java and probably a solution with spring batch would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/snowflake-jdbc-postgresql-fdw.rst), you can create a **foreign data wrapper** on Postgresql for snowflake